# WebSocket error in common lisp

Tags: websocket, openssl, common-lisp

I want to make slack bot.
I can not solve this error.

```
(ql:quickload '(:cl-slack
             :event-emitter
             :websocket-driver
             :jonathan
             :cl-async
             )
          :silent t)

(defconstant +token+ "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
(defconstant +channel+ "xxx")
(defvar *client* (make-instance 'cl-slack.core:slack-client
                            :token +token+))

(let ((url (getf (jonathan:parse (cl-slack.rtm:start *client* nil)) :|url|)))
  (format t url)
  (defparameter *slack-bot* (wsd:make-client url)))

(defun params (id type channel text)
(jonathan:to-json (list :|id|      id
                      :|type|    type
                      :|channel| channel
                      :|text|    text)))

(wsd:on :message *slack-bot*
    (lambda (message)
      (let ((data (jonathan:parse message)))
        (format t "~A~%" data)
        (when (string= (getf data :|type|) "message")
          (wsd:send *slack-bot*
                    (params 1
                            "message"
                            (getf data :|channel|)
                            (getf data :|text|)))))))

(as:with-event-loop (:catch-app-errors t)
                (wsd:start-connection *slack-bot*))
```

error is

> [20:42:25] cl-async-util - handle-error: SSL verify error: 20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Comment: This is not really a problem about Common Lisp, slack, or websockets. I suppose you could say it’s a problem about wss. Strictly speaking this is a problem about OpenSSL. The error says that OpenSSL doesn’t have a local copy of the certificate of the CA which issued the certificate that slack uses. Therefore it cannot tell whether the certificate slack presents is valid. You need to work out how to get OpenSSL a copy of that root certificate (or get it to ignore the problem and not check certificates)

Comment: Thank you.
I do not check for now.

Comment: I try to avoid checking certificates.
I could do it.
My 'websocket-driver' is old.
I update 'websocket-driver'
    `ros install fukamachi/websocket-driver`
And I rewrite program.
    `(wsd:start-connection *slack-bot*) ->`,
    `(wsd:start-connection *slack-bot* :verify nil)`
As a result, I can avoid checking vertificates.